# custom/automatic export function - one post at a time?

Tags: plugins, customization, export

Here is my challenge;
I run a real-estate site for a customer.
When an apartment or house is sold, it stays as "sold" a couple of weeks, and then is deleted from the site (keeping it tidy).
However. A year later (or more), this same property might be for sale again. And the customer want to get the data for this property back into the site again (so he does not have to write everything all over again).
My thoughs:
Create a simple export function that exports the property before it is deleted. Keeping the wxr-files sorted in a year/month type of structure.
It would be easy to just import the data, and less time used for finding the data in old databases ...
So far:
I found an "Export one" plugin, and that works fine when exporting manually, and saving manually.
And I've done a couple of tries with using the url's used by the export one plugin, without luck, because the session data from my wordpress login is not kept when doing e.g. a file_put_contents(..)

Anyone have a plugin, idea or any pointer to how I can solve this?

Comment: If you're only trying to keep your admin clean (and not your database) you can create a custom post status "Sold" with `register_post_status`. You'll be able to hide your posts in posts list table when you'll make your export and get them back with only a status change on the website.

Comment: Most important is keeping the admin clean, yes.
This might actually be the best way to solve this particular problem, thanks :).
Still curious if someone have any idea on exporting posts one by one though...